# adjust image button size in android eclipse

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I need help for adjusting image button size, l down loaded a blue button when l want to change the width to mach parent the blue image button size hasn't changed it crate grey button and the blue button stay as the same size on the default grey button.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/btnbluee" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `background` instead of `src` -

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btnbluee" />
```